# How to install local packages using pip as part of a docker build?

Tags: python, docker, pip

I've got a package that I want to build into a docker image which depends on an adjacent package on my system.

My `requirements.txt` looks something like this:

```
-e ../other_module
numpy==1.0.0
flask==0.12.5
```

When I call `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a virtualenv this works fine. However, if I call this in a Dockerfile, e.g.:

```
ADD requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and run using `docker build .` I get an error saying the following:

`../other_module should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+`

What, if anything, am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have that `other_module` in the Docker image?

Comment: Hade you added `../other_module` to the docker image as well?

Comment: @9000 @Cleared I've tried to copy it using something like `COPY ../other_module /app` but that renders a different error: `Forbidden path outside the build context`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all, you need to add `other_module` to your Docker image. Without that, the `pip install` command will not be able to find it. However you can `ADD` a directory that is outside the directory of the Dockerfile according to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD
> ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is
> to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
> daemon.

So you have to move the `other_module` directory into the same directory as your Dockerfile, i.e. your structure should look something like

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
├── other_module
|   ├── modue_file.xyz
|   └── another_module_file.xyz
```

then add the following to the dockerfile:

```
ADD /other_module /other_module
ADD requirements.txt /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The `WORKDIR` command moves you into `/app` so the next step, `RUN pip install...` will be executed inside the `/app` directory. And from the app-directory, you now have the directory`../other_module` avaliable

Comment: One thing I'd add to this is that with this approach, one does not need to edit their requirements.txt file -- when developing locally you can run `pip install -e ../other_module/` to get your local copy of the library, and in the Docker file after copying you can just add the same command.

Comment: So if several projects have dependencies to `other_module` then all these projects need to make a copy of say `../other_module` to `./other_module` so it's available when building the docker image?  Isn't there a better way (not involving copying for example)? Is a symlink sufficient for this to work?

Comment: @cglacet I'd be interested in knowing this too. At least, if you are working using Google Cloud Build or similars, you can publish the package in a registry and then pip install it remotely from the container.